# Livestream of prerecorded flv videos with ffmpeg and red5

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, red5, rtmp, live-streaming

My goal is to acheive the following steps :-

1. rtmp livestream of prerecoreded flv videos using ffmpeg.
2. videos should be played continuously just like a tv station.

We are currently using red5 and ffmpeg to acheive this goal and we have successfully published the live stream of prerecorded single video to jwplayer using the following conversion command :

```
for i in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i $i -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/livestream
```

But the problem comes when we need to livestream two videos one after the other. User have to click play button again in order to stream second video which is not a tv-station thing instead we need to continuously play stream for user instead of clicking on play button on ending of each stream.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful, concatenating media files using ffmpeg:

http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest, as an alternative, to use Wowza Streaming Engine (commercial software, though developer license is free, but with limit on connections and 180 day validity). I tried the ffmpeg concatenation route, but all in all just a big mess with huge files.

With Wowza You can quite easily create your own playlists with scheduling, put it on repeat etc, through creating your own simple modules in Java or using the premade modules ( http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145-How-to-schedule-streaming-with-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-ServerListenerStreamPublisher )

I've done this and have several live streams of prerecorded video files.